# REST Handling a wrong Parameter and required parameter

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

My requirement is to get the json response with customized error message when a required `@RequestParam` is not sent to the request handler or invalid parameter(required is int but user is passing string) is sent to the request handler.

currently I am trying to use the `@Exceptionhandler` mechanism to handle these exceptions. But the respective exception handler methods not getting invoked.

Please see the code snippet:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("api/v1/getDetails")
public class Abc {


@RequestMapping
@ResponseBody
public Envelope<Object> retrieveTransactions(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer a,
        @RequestParam int b, @RequestParam(required = false) boolean c,
        HttpServletRequest req) {`
//implementation goes here
}

@ExceptionHandler(MissingServletRequestParameterException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Envelope<Object> missingParameterExceptionHandler(Exception exception,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    Envelope<Object> envelope = null;
   //error implementation
    return envelope;
}

@ExceptionHandler(TypeMismatchException.class)
@ResponseBody
public Envelope<Object> typeMismatchExpcetionHandler(Exception exception, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Envelope<Object> envelope = null;
   //error implementation
    return envelope;

}
```

Do I need to configure anything extra for exception handler? can anyone tell me where I am doing the wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `MethodArgumentNotValidException` or `HttpMessageNotReadableException` instead on your handlers?

And put `required = true` on your @RequestParam declaration to catch missing params exceptions

```
@RequestParam(required = true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider identifying the parameter name in the RequestParameter annotation.
For example

```
@RequestParam(value="blammy", required=false)
```

I've never bothered figuring out how to handle type mismatch,
instead I've found it easier to accept all parameters as String and perform all verification myself (including type).

Also,
If you are accepting the HttpServletRequest as a parameter to your handler,
then there is no need to use @RequestParam annotations,
just get the parameter values directly from the request.

Finally,
consider org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest 
or org.springframework.web.context.request.NativeWebRequest
instead of HttpServletRequest.